# I want to make the constraint as a billiard cue ball works

Tags: javascript, matter.js

I am working on this pool ball game in Matterjs.

I have a problem with a constraint.

I want to make it work like billiard cue ball, that when the user pushes, it should have the elastic behavior but then it should move straight. But due to pointA it doesn't work for me.

Here is the snippet:

```js
var anchor = {
    x: cue.position.x,
    y: cue.position.y
  },
  elastic = Constraint.create({
    pointA: anchor,
    bodyB: cue,
    stiffness: 0.05,
    render: {
      lineWidth: 0.5
    }
  });

Events.on(engine, 'tick', function() {
  if (mouseConstraint.mouse.button === -1 &&
       (cue.position.x > 170 || cue.position.y < 330)) {
    elastic.bodyB = cue;
    //want to update the pointA here but not able to.
  }
});

var mouse = Mouse.create(render.canvas),
  mouseConstraint = MouseConstraint.create(engine, {
    mouse: mouse,
    constraint: {
      stiffness: 0.2,
      render: {
        visible: false
      }
    }
  });

World.add(world, mouseConstraint);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How does it not work for your?

Comment: For me, it's an elastic constraint that binds that cue ball to its center.
For the preview take this example: http://brm.io/matter-js/demo/#slingshot

Comment: The ball is always intact to the center, which is pointA of constraint. I want to always update this point as the ball moves. But the ball should have elastic property for which there should be a pointA.